# Where can I find sql server agent service logs?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-agent

I am using SQL server 2014.

I notice that - occasionally, the sql server agent service gets automatically stopped.

Where can I find logs to check the timing of when the service stop has happened and what has caused the service to stop?

Note: I am not asking for agent job logs. I want the agent service logs.

Answer (score 3):

In Object Explorer, there is a folder at the bottom called Error Logs, you can see them in there. Right clicking on the folder and choosing Configure will show you where they're stored, and what things are being tracked.

[image]

Comment: This log holds the job related logs. Does this have the sql agent service logs?

Comment: Yes, you will see a stop message if the service stops. Try it out in a dev instance, stop the the agent, then start the agent. You should see the stop message in the 2nd latest log file, not the current one. 

You can also query it with xp_readerrorlog. 

Current agent error log:
EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 0,2
Previous one:
EXEC xp_ReadErrorLog 1,2